# Kotlin null handling - making buttons transparent or hiding them

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Why does my app crash after pressing button which makes buttons transparent, it says that Reading a NULL string not supported here.

```kotlin
    lateinit var Button1: Button
    lateinit var Button2: Button


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Button1= view?.findViewById(R.id.btn1)
        Button2 = view?.findViewById(R.id.btn2)


        Button1?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        Button2?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }
```

Logs

```
E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.soE/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E/ScreenmodeClient:  display mode not support
```

Please help me quickly.

Comment: Please, add the logs to the question.

Comment: @MustafaKhaled added

Comment: I want to somehow make my buttons disappear after clicking a button and opening another fragment. As they overlap text, is there any way to move them behind a background made of white component?

Comment: where is your setContentView() method.

Comment: I do not use it, I just created buttons in xml, and want them removed, after clicking a button

Comment: When entering another fragment @RudraRokaya

Comment: The provided log is not a full stacktrace of the error; please update it with the entire stacktrace

Comment: the button will not disappear if you set the background transparent , use `setVisibility` and `View.GONE` to make it disappear, or you can set `isEnable = false` to disable the button, and probably your app crash because method  `findViewById` return `null`

Answer (score 1):

According to your code and exception you said, I think the button may be null, but you define it as `lateinit`, which means you create later but it can not be null.

Firstly you should make sure the buttons exist, then change the button defines as the following:

````
    var Button1: Button? = null
    var Button2: Button? = null


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Button1= view?.findViewById(R.id.btn1)
        Button2 = view?.findViewById(R.id.btn2)


        Button1?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        Button2?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }

```
the other way is not to use `?`, because the view has to exit.

```
    lateinit var Button1: Button
    lateinit var Button2: Button


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Button1= view.findViewById(R.id.btn1)
        Button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn2)


        Button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        Button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

TRY this -

OPTION 1-

```
     lateinit var button1: AppCompatButton
        lateinit var button2: AppCompatButton

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Button1)
        button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.Button2)

        button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
```

Option 2- Simply add in button -

> android:background="@null"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Button1" />
```